# Wordpress menu links stop working intermittently

Tags: wordpress

This issue started occurring today: the menu links stop working intermittently (I try clicking, and nothing happens) and I can only get them to start working again by doing a few refreshes. Then again, after moving around the menu a few times, the links stop working.

I noticed this problem on the localhost and then, to test it, I uploaded the website to a webspace and the problem is still there (also tried two different computers, clearing cache, etc.).

The test page is here: http://toulouse.xardas.lima-city.de/en/

I have deactivated several plugins and tried retracing my steps to see if anything I did today could have caused it (I mainly worked on changing the image sizes on the main page in CSS), but I couldn't find the cause.

I have tried the trick where you re-save the permalinks once with a new structure, and then change them back to what they were again and save. That didn't help.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: The first thing I'd suggest is disabling your plugins one-by-one to see if any of them are including code that is affecting how the site works.

Comment: Thanks, I disabled all the plugins I added recently but it didn't help. I went back to an earlier version of the website where the links still worked, and as I add back all the changes I made, maybe I can work out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem its not related to plugins, your website has 2 critical javascript errors that show up on the console and they seem to be disabling your website Javascript:

1. jquery.min.js is no able to load.
2. masonry.pkgd.js is not able to load.

Both errors are occurring because WordPress its trying to load them from a local server of yours (127.0.0.1).

Since your website its not on a local server, you need to change the  tag that refers to those scripts and update the src to the real address of those libraries.

You can need to make sure that this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elisabethzeigt-topmenu/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Gets replaced with this:

```
<script src="http://toulouse.xardas.lima-city.de/wp-content/themes/elisabethzeigt-topmenu/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The only thing that was updated was the initial part of the src: "*http://toulouse.xardas.lima-city.de/*" instead of "*http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/*".

Remember: You should to the same to the other script tag of the masonry library.

**If you don't know how to replace them**: just search for "jquery" and "masonry.pkgd.js" in your functions.php file and you will find the lines of code.

There is a chance that you functions.php has a global variable with the path to your website and you can fix the issue updating that variable instead of the scripts.

Comment: Yes you're right, that was a stupid mistake, thanks! I fixed it, but it's not the cause as I have the same problem on the local server, where the links work (I also deleted them to see if it has an effect). I am reverting the website back to an earlier version now, as I can't work out the problem :/ Luckily I haven't made that many changes between the backups. As I am adding back the changes I made, maybe I can work out the cause and I'll post it here if I do.